# Generate xml output from a hash table input

Tags: xml, windows, powershell

I would like to perform a string formation and result to be an XML variable. Here is the sample input that I have to convert to a valid xml,

```
$ps_hash_table =@{
  "Category01" = @(
                  'C1I1',
                  'C1I2',
                  'C1I3'
   );
  "Category02" = @(
                  'C2I1',
                  'C2I2',
                  'C2I3'
   );
}
```

I would need an xml output in this format,

```
<Categories>
   <list>C1I1</list>
   <list>C1I2</list>
   <list>C1I3</list>
   <list>C2I1</list>
   <list>C2I2</list>
   <list>C2I3</list>
</Categories>
```

I was able to get this in regular looping to format as an xml string but looking for an optimal or better ways of generating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would just use an `[Xml.XmlWriter]` object for this.

```
$xmlsettings = [xml.xmlwritersettings]::new()
$xmlsettings.indent = $true
$xmlsettings.omitxmldeclaration = $true
$xml = [xml.xmlwriter]::create('xml.xml',$xmlsettings)
$xml.writestartelement('Categories')
$ps_hash_table.values | Foreach-Object {
    $_ | Foreach-Object {
        $xml.writeelementstring('list',$_)
    }
}
$xml.writeendelement()
$xml.flush()
$xml.close()
```

Now `xml.xml` will contain your xml formatted string

---

To store XML string in a variable without using a file, you can use a `MemoryStream` object:

```
$xmlsettings = [xml.xmlwritersettings]::new()
$xmlsettings.indent = $true
$xmlsettings.omitxmldeclaration = $true
$xmlsettings.encoding = [text.encoding]::UTF8::new($false)
$stream = [io.memorystream]::new()
$xml = [xml.xmlwriter]::create($stream,$xmlsettings)
$xml.writestartelement('Categories')
$ps_hash_table.values | Foreach-Object {
    $_ | Foreach-Object {
        $xml.writeelementstring('list',$_)
    }
}
$xml.writeendelement()
$xml.flush()
$xml.close()
$output = [text.encoding]::UTF8.GetString($stream.ToArray())
$stream.Dispose()
$stream.Close()
```

Now `$output` contains your string. The `UTF8` encoding with `$false` prevents the BOM from being added when using Windows PowerShell. It is not necessary in PowerShell Core. The byte stream conversion to string has unreadable characters when the BOM is present.

Comment: But this generates an output file, right? Can I use xmlwriter to write to a variable instead of file?

Comment: @sqlcheckpoint I added a version using a variable. This can be much simpler if you don't care about maintaining spacing in your XML string.